# How to add a Button in the JW Player control bar using Javascript API?

Tags: jwplayer

The official documentation has a method -

```
addButton(icon, label, handler, id)
```

But this adds a button in the Video area.

I want to add a button in the control bar besides the Play Pause button.
Is there any option in the JW Player.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3443/1/)

PS - I dont want to insert html on my own in the player. I want to use a built in function.

Comment: You can see my answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36430044/1386969

Dont forget to smile :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to do that. addButton adds a button over the video.
You can follow this pull request:

Add custom control bar buttons #126

https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/pull/126

Comment: Indeed, addButton is for dock buttons only, right now.

Answer (score 0):

Download source code from github and add as many buttons you want,,,, the only way